# Submit form before user leaves page in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

Is it possible to create a more customized leaving-page event? 
Right now I am using the `window.onbeforeunload` event to warn users of their unsaved changes before leaving the page.

What I really want to do though, is to give the user the option to save their data right away before leaving the page(possibly with a button in a pop up) and then continue redirecting them. I assume it's not possible to let `onbeforeunload` do some extra work before displaying the message(I tried).

So is what I want even possible or a good idea?

Comment: this question is potentially better suited to http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model used by most large sites (including stack) is simply to warn users that they have unsaved data. I suggest you replicate that behaviour.

Comment: I've decided to just go with this. Trying to customize the behaviour just seems like too much trouble for something that users probably don't care that much about.

Comment: thanks. Keeping a conventions users are familiar with is important.

Answer (score 0):

You're not the first one that wants to handle a user leaving the page gracefully.

Unfortunately `onBeforeUnload` is what you have available and that's what you have to work with.

The reason that it is only possible to show a message is that otherwise evil sites might try to cancel the navigation to prevent the user from leaving the page.

Answer (score 0):

If u use PHP, u can do it with onbeforeunload and ajax, like

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function close_logout() {
 var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "logout_script.php", true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onbeforeunload="close_logout()">
U'r page and stuff
</body>
</html>
```

Then u can have some PHP function and so on in the php site.