# Submitting form on click of back button of browser

Tags: jquery, form-submit, back-button

i have a jsp page which contains 2 forms as follows:

```
<form action=cancelRide.html id="cancel" method="get">
    <button type="submit" name="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
<form action=confirmRide.html method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="book">Book</button>
</form>
```

And on the click of cancel button it goes to cancelRide controller.I need the same thing to happen when the back button of the browser clicked .That is when the back button is clicked I need the cancelRide form to be submitted.

Comment: I know jquery mobile has a navigate event but I don't think regular jquery does: http://api.jquerymobile.com/navigate/

Comment: a back button on your browser? or a back button on your page that you coded?

Comment: You might want to start with this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser

Comment: And this one can help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594413/js-or-jquery-browser-back-button-click-detector

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   $( "#back" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).parent().submit();
    });
```

if the back button is right inside the form as in your example or

```
$( "#back" ).click(function() {
  $( "#back_form" ).submit();
});
```

otherwise.

Comment: the back button I referred to is browser's back button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322042/jquery-warn-if-leaving-page-without-clicking-the-save-button

Comment: I think you may use this technique. Use window.onbeforeunload event trigger.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039815/submit-form-before-user-leaves-page-in-javascript-jquery